# How to save specific users answers in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

This is probably a dumb question and probably not possible but what I am looking to do is I have created an NHL drop and drag board on JSFiddle for my friends and I. Is there a way to have their answers saved so if they click back on the fiddle their results will still be shown from their last use.

This is what i'm using for the drag and drop

```
$(function() {
  $(".draggable").draggable();
   $(".item").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.append(ui.draggable);

      var width = $this.width();
      var height = $this.height();
      var cntrLeft = (width / 2) - (ui.draggable.width() / 2);
      var cntrTop = (height / 2) - (ui.draggable.height() / 0.50);

      ui.draggable.css({
        left: cntrLeft + "px",
        top: cntrTop + "px"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This is the link to the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/NickBonino/537wtvjv/2/

I just want it so that when they drag and drop their players to the left, the next time they come back to view the fiddle their response should still be there

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Sounds like you need a database which jsFiddle won't give you

Comment: I dont really want to store them I kinda just want to save the answers online. Just so that when they get home their answers would be the same as when they left them

Comment: If that makes any sense

Comment: The web by default is stateless, so you'd have to store the data somewhere

Comment: Take a look at Google's FireBase. With a bit of JS you can see your actions saved and displayed on jsFiddle or wherever you want.

Comment: Or you can save their positions into their LocalStorage (though those changes will not be *live* for everyone)

Comment: See I was kinda thinking something along the lines of your second comment but i really dont know how to go about doing that. I will however look into firebase